# Php variable increment

Tags: php, loops, variables, mysqli

So i have the following code that works and outputs the information let's say `2 11`. I would like to have `$keyidcall` increment in variable name so `$keyidcall2, $keyidcall3.......` with the additional variables I would like the variable to hold the correct value so I can call it later. so expected output would be `$Apiammount ="2"`;
`echo $keyidcall;` would echo `2`
`echo $keyidcall`: would echo `11`

```
while($Apiammount > 1){
    $Keyidquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ID FROM `Characterapi` WHERE UserId = '$Idcall'");
    while($keyid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Keyidquery)){
        $keyidcall = $keyid['ID'];
        echo $keyidcall;
    }

    $Apiammount--;
}
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself using numbered variables like that, you almost always should use an array instead.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think I know of *any* need for it

Comment: Neither do I, but I try to avoid absolutes.

Comment: Looking at your code, the `$Keyidquery ` will be the same all the time, since '$Idcall' is not changed anywhere in the loop. 
If you want to return the same value and store it in multiple variables there is no need to run the query over and over again. Once you got that sorted, as @Adam Copley suggested, store them in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do this would be to store the values in an array.

`$keyidcall[] = $keyid['ID'];`

Then you can refer to them later as

`echo $keyidcall[0];`
`echo $keyidcall[1];`

in the order that they were entered in.

Or if you wanted something more specific to refer to it by, you could use

`$keyidcall[$Apiammount] = $keyid['ID'];`

then you would refer to them as:

`echo $keyidcall[<apiamount>];`

Assuming you know what that would be.

Comment: So after realiising i needed to create the array this worked AMAYAZINGLY. TY

Comment: now is there a way i can use the $keyidcall[] in a msqli query where i can do upon $keyidcall[0] = 3 in a my msqli query the call uses the three and i can loop it ?

Comment: I recommend you post a separate question and link in these comments. What your asking needs a little more detail

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do:

```
$i = 0;
while($foo){
  $name = 'keyidcall';
  $i++;
  $newvar = $name . $i;
  echo $$newvar;
}
```

And $$newvar will echo the value of "keyidcallX" where X is an incrementing value. Not sure if that's what you meant.